# T-SQL Insert into in the BEGIN CATCH

Tags: sql-server, exception, upsert

Thanks in advance for the help.

What I'm trying to achieve is handling the constraint violation of the FK (Municipality code) and when that's the case I want to insert the record in a fallout table.

In this block of code there result of the select can be null and therefore will throw an exception as I have a not null clause on the target.

`TARGET.MUNICIPALITYCODE = (SELECT m.MUNICIPALITYCODE FROM MUNICIPALITY m WHERE SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE = m.MUNICIPALITYCODE)`

I wanted to be able to treat the exception on the BEGIN CATCH block and INSERT into a table of my choice the values that I was using on the SOURCE.

Does anyone knows if it is possible?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upsertStagingToStreet
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRAN

           MERGE STREET AS TARGET
           USING STREET_STAGING AS SOURCE
           ON (TARGET.correlationkey = SOURCE.correlationkey)

           WHEN MATCHED 
           THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Qty = SOURCE.Qty,
                TARGET.MUNICIPALITYCODE = (SELECT m.MUNICIPALITYCODE FROM MUNICIPALITY m WHERE SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE = m.MUNICIPALITYCODE)

           WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
            THEN INSERT (MUNICIPALITYCODE, STREENAME,STREECODE) VALUE ((SELECT m.MUNICIPALITYCODE FROM MUNICIPALITY m WHERE SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE = m.MUNICIPALITYCODE),SOURCE.STREETCODE,SOURCE.STREETCODE)

        COMMIT
    END TRY
    begin catch
        # I'm not able to figure this part out.
        INSERT INTO STREET_FALLOUT (MUNICIPALITYCODE, STREENAME,STREECODE,ERRORREASON) VALUES (SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE,STREETNAME,STREETCODE,ERROR_MESSAGE())
    end catch
```

Comment: Your current construct is not going to work to accomplish what you want. The catch block is a different statement so you can't just grab values from your merge. And the concept violates the Atomic portion of ACID. Meaning you can't arbitrarily insert some data and not others. It is all part of the same transaction.

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way, possible an `instead of` trigger will give you the control you need.

Comment: @SeanLange i was afraid of this reply. I've actually considered that but wanted feedback in case if there was another option :/ i guess i need to create a procedure that actually avoids the exceptions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this wrong. It is not possible to insert some of the rows and catch errors on others.

Instead, just query the non-matching rows, and merge only the matching ones.

- Note the lack of error-handling, and the inclusion of `XACT_ABORT ON`. This is the correct way, as all errors will cause the transaction to rollback anyway.
- Note the `SOURCE` table in the merge is pre-joined with `MUNICIPALITY`, so only matching rows can appear.
- A `MERGE` statement *must* have a semi-colon terminator, which is good practice anyway.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE upsertStagingToStreet
AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN


INSERT INTO STREET_FALLOUT
    (MUNICIPALITYCODE, STREENAME, STREECODE, ERRORREASON)
SELECT
  SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE,
  SOURCE.STREETCODE,
  SOURCE.STREETCODE,
  'Missing MUNICIPALITYCODE'
FROM STREET_STAGING AS SOURCE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM MUNICIPALITY m
    WHERE SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE = m.MUNICIPALITYCODE
);


WITH SOURCE AS (
    SELECT SOURCE.*
    FROM STREET_STAGING AS SOURCE
    JOIN MUNICIPALITY m ON SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE = m.MUNICIPALITYCODE
)
MERGE STREET AS TARGET
USING SOURCE
  ON (TARGET.correlationkey = SOURCE.correlationkey)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    Qty = SOURCE.Qty,
    MUNICIPALITYCODE = SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (MUNICIPALITYCODE, STREENAME, STREECODE)
  VALUES (SOURCE.MUNICIPALITYCODE, SOURCE.STREETCODE, SOURCE.STREETCODE)
;

COMMIT;

GO
```